# Using SQL Server 2016 Merge function

Tags: sql-server, merge, insert

I have a table *digital_calendar_event* with the columns : *dce_date*, *dce_event_name*, *dce_event_icone*

The data are shown in an editable Datagrid, where the event name or Icone can be modified. I can't know if it is an Update or Insert (i don't want to use an Id, here the date is a primary unique key)
I've heard that the Merge function can check if the value exists, here my primary key is *dce_date*

Plus I need to detect if the user has deleted the values (*dce_event_name* or *dce_event_icone*) in the datagrid

I want to Use the merge function but I onl have one table and in a merge it seems like I need a source table...

Edit : I used a IF EXIST statement but in the *ELSE* part it seems I can't put a CASE WHEN statement

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT dce_date FROM digital_calendar_event where dce_date = @CurrentDate)
UPDATE digital_calendar_event set dce_event_name = @EventName, dce_event_icone = @EventIcone
--- incorrect syntax near 'CASE'
ELSE CASE 
   WHEN @EventName ='' and @EventIcone = '' THEN DELETE FROM digital_calendar_event WHERE dce_date = @CurrentDate
   WHEN @EventName <> '' or @EventIcone <> '' THEN INSERT INTO digital_calendar_event (dce_date, dce_event_name, dce_event_icone) VALUES(@CurrentDate, @EventName , @EventIcone)
END
```

How to do so ? The SQL code I wrote is exactly what I need but if doesn't work...

Comment: you can have identify from one key column. How merge will come to know row is updated, inserted or deleted.

Comment: @DeepakKumar My one primary key Column is Unique, like an Id but here it is a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Deepak Kumar here is the answer :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT dce_date FROM digital_calendar_event where dce_date = @CurrentDate)
BEGIN
    IF  @EventName ='' and @EventIcone = '' 
        BEGIN
        DELETE FROM digital_calendar_event WHERE dce_date = @CurrentDate
        END
   ELSE UPDATE digital_calendar_event set dce_event_name = @EventName, dce_event_icone = @EventIcone
END
ELSE-- else of if exists
  BEGIN
    IF @EventName <> '' or @EventIcone <> '' 
    INSERT INTO digital_calendar_event (dce_date, dce_event_name, dce_event_icone) VALUES(@CurrentDate, @EventName , @EventIcone)
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try like below query -

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT dce_date FROM digital_calendar_event where dce_date = @CurrentDate)
Begin
UPDATE digital_calendar_event set dce_event_name = @EventName, dce_event_icone = @EventIcone

ELSE 

if  @EventName ='' and @EventIcone = '' 
Begin
DELETE FROM digital_calendar_event WHERE dce_date = @CurrentDate

ENd


   Else IF @EventName <> '' or @EventIcone <> '' 
   Begin
   INSERT INTO digital_calendar_event (dce_date, dce_event_name, dce_event_icone) VALUES(@CurrentDate, @EventName , @EventIcone)

   END
END
```

Comment: Thanks ! It is not exactly correct but I  helps me A LOT , I posted the answer thanks to you :)